# Can I change the sort sequence of a SOLR search at query time? Make SOLR use 52734 instead of 12345?

Tags: sorting, dynamic, solr, lexical

I have documents in an index which have a category attribute.

There are priorities assigned to each category, like so:

```
Category | Priority
    1    |     1
    2    |     2
    3    |     3
    4    |     4
```

I wish to be able to change how SOLR sorts by the category attribute, at query time, so that I can decide that category 4 should be priority 1, without having to reindex all the documents.

For instance, something like this:

```
order by category asc, with ordering of "4123"
```

Then if a document has category 4, it will come before a document with category of 1.

Is this possible in SOLR?

Also, I am using this priority to order **groups of documents**, not overall sorting.

Answer (score 1):

you could achieve that follows that order by using map function, see [here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Sorting-function-with-condition-td2970036.html), although the function could be a bit long and hard to understand.